# Bash Find File check IF and execute

Tags: bash, shell, command, jq

i have this files

```
1.json2    - 2.json2    - 3.json2
1.json2.ml - 2.json2.ml -
```

Example  ml file

```
1.json2.ml
{"message":"Validation error","error":"validation_error",...

2.json2.ml
{"Ok":"OK":"OK"...}
```

I want  to search  if  *.json2.ml isnt execute a post and save.
If the  file exist  look if error is there and  execute  Post.

Here is the code i use for this

```
   find . -type f -name '*.json2' | xargs bash -c 'for fname
do if [ ! -e ${fname}.ml ]
then curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @${fname} https://web/api/post > ${fname}.ml  


else

sed '1d' ${fname}.ml  | while read line
do
FS=',' read pid pname
if [ "$var" -e ""error":"validation_error"" ] 
then 
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @${fname} https://web/api/post > ${fname}.ml
 echo  que ha y $pname


fi

done

' bash
```

I have this result

```
syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
```

What is the expected result

```
1 - Post  3.json2 ( file .ml no exist )
2-  Post  1.json2 ( File .ml exist and  have error in )
3- 2.json2 and  3.json2 ( do nothing because json2.ml is OK)
```

Comment: You're using single quote as the delimiter around the `bash -c` parameter, and also around strings that are inside it. Those inner quotes are ending the string.

Comment: It looks like you didn't copy the whole script. It ends in the middle of a `while` loop.

Comment: Use double quotes around strings that are inside the single quotes, like `sed "1d"`

Comment: Although, in this case the single quotes around the `1d` argument to `sed` is not actually causing a problem.  It terminates the string, but you can simply omit them.  However, your script is clearly truncated, since there is no instance of `fi` anywhere.

Comment: Doing complex scripting inside the arguments to xargs is a bad idea.  Write a script, put it in a file, make it executable, and invoke it.

Comment: I change the '  for " and nothing happend =(

Answer (score 0):

I  found the solution   whit this code

```
    else
VAR1=$(head -n 1 ${fname}.ml)
IFS="," read -ra images <<< "$VAR1"


 echo  que ha y $images
```

Thx alot to Barmar and William